# Are there performance/security issues or benefits when parsing SQL data to JSON to allow a user to login to a website? If so, what are they?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm sorry if the title is a little confusing or misleading, it'll probably get changed once I get some sleep, but here's my question.  Is there a benefit to creating a login system based off a JSON file?  For instance, I have a pretty standard login system that has the user connect to a database and keeps the connection open for the duration that they're logged in.  Pretty simple and standard.  But I was wondering, instead of having the user actually connect to the database, would it be better(security & performance wise) to instead, have PHP output the SQL tables to a JSON file and close the connection, and then run the login checks based on the JSON file instead of actually having the user be logged into the database?  Sorry if this question is confusing or if I'm not clear with what I'm asking.

Comment: Use the database to validate user credentials and if you are using php as stated at the top, start a session and fill it with whatever necessary details, username, id etc you have for that user. Try to send as little as possible to them. Think of JSON as just a transport method for you to send data to the user to process in JavaScript.

Comment: @Lucas that's actually what I'm asking, I know the question title and body are pretty confusing, I wrote it when I was half asleep.  So it would be a good idea to parse the data into JSON and then process it in JS, without keeping the DB connection open?

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing @Robert, if you have something on the page you are calling that requires JSON then by all means `echo json_encode($whatever_values_you_care_to_send)`. Broadly speaking there should be no additional security/performance issues sending JSON over... tables, paragraphs, images, whatever, it really depends on what or how much you are sending - if you require a more specific answer you will have to make your question more specific.

Comment: @Lucas actually, your comment answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the industrial standard practice is to check the login once (when the user login to the system) and then create a session out of that. And you can store any data related to current login in that session.  Every time a server gets a request it will check the session first and if the session is valid it will return back the details required and there is no interaction with the database (By default PHP store the session data in file, you can change to any storage engine as you like) for validating the user.

Also creating a json file with all the data in user table is not going to be a good practice because it will cause performance problem as you start scaling.